# playercontrols.cs(11,26): error CS1513: ; expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

playercontrols.cs(11,26): error CS 1513: }expected
I started making games 2 days ago. Now im making my first game and I have error. I don't know how to solve this problem this is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontrols : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
    rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(1,rb.velocity.y);
    onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround);
    {

        rb.velocity=new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few errors in your code:

- too many semicolons ';',
- too few closing curly brackets...

Here is fixed code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontrols : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

      rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, rb.velocity.y);
      onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && onGround)
      {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 3);
      }
    }
}
```

Since both were beginners mistakes, I would strongly suggest (before making any games) to go through some tutorials on C# that covers all topics on programming in C#. Since human aren't bee's, we humans need first to learn how to do something.